# How to get right element in array

Tags: excel

I'm really sory with this stupid title. But i don't think an other title.
I think that i'm wrong at `RIGHT(I37:M37,1)/1` but i do not know how to fix it.
Could you help me, please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `VLOOKUP` use `INDEX MATCH`.

```
{=INDEX($I$37:$M$40, MATCH(LEFT(I32, 1), $I$37:$I$40, 0), MATCH(RIGHT(I32, 1), RIGHT($I$37:$M$37, 1), 0))}
```

This is an array formula so enter with `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`

[image]

Comment: i'm sorry but i get a result is #N/A

Comment: Works fine in testing. Are you sure all your G, H, C, Class 1, Class 2 etc don't have trailing spaces, and you entered the above as an array formula?

Comment: i'm sure, can you test again your formula, thank you so much

Comment: Erm ok, tested again and it works. Put my formula in your sheet and upload a new screenshot so i can see you are using it correctly.

Comment: i'm not sure with this uploading way
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpxwm.png
_____
http://imgur.com/K52kI0V

Comment: Ok so you are not using my formula exactly, whats with the `RIGHT($I$37:$M$37, 1)/1` ? Get rid of that `/1`.

Comment: i added it after i using your formula exactly.

Comment: so at that time i take a screenshot, a forget removing it

Comment: I'm afraid im not sure what else to try then, when duplicating your data exactly, the formula above works. I have added a screen shot. can you try this quickly `=INDEX($I$37:$M$40, MATCH(LEFT(TRIM(I32), 1), TRIM($I$37:$I$40), 0), MATCH(RIGHT(TRIM(I32), 1), RIGHT(TRIM($I$37:$M$37), 1), 0))` (again hit CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER)

Comment: i'm sorry coz not quickly, your formula above worked

Comment: Right, the formula above just trims any trailing spaces from all values, which we got to on the second comment "Are you sure all your G, H, C, Class 1, Class 2 etc don't have trailing spaces?". Anyway glad it works.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very useful knowledge i have from you. Thank you so much again.

Comment: Could you help me a addition question
Example i have Class 1,2,3,4 with Group 1.  And other Class 1,2,3,4 with Group 4.
Now i want to get result from Group 2 puted next to Group
What do I need?

This is example image for my present. https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZJ5p.png

Thank you.

Comment: Post a new question with this example so more people will see it and be able to assist.

Comment: But I received a notification that "You have reached your question limit".
It could be 2 questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community.
Could you please help me this topic?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273741/stack-overflow-you-have-reached-your-question-limit

Comment: I can't see those questions so you must have deleted them, which looks bad on SO and can cause this question limit. Best bet is it undelete them, and edit them to be better questions to receive upvotes and lift this question limit.

Comment: Thank you but i have not understood yet. I think i could solve this problem after.